# How do I append multiple lists to one key in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, python-2.x

I want to append values to a key in a dictionary, where the values are actually lists. There could be one list, or there could be multiple lists.

The current way I'm trying to do it, the new list I try to add on just overwrites the last list. As far as I can tell, I can't append a list to a dict like so either:

```
my_dict.append(my_list))
```

Current code that overwrites each other:

```
urls[domain] = [uri, datecreated]
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Sample results would look like this

```
print all keys and values in urls{}:
google.com : ['/helloworld', 2010-04-02], ['/apage/anotherpage', 2015-09-12] 
microsoft.com : ['/awebpage', 2009-02-01], ['/bananas', 2015-12-24], ['/anothergreaturi', 205-12-10]
```

Comment: We need a sample dictionary and the desired result, it is not completely clear what you are asking.

Comment: Added  sample at the end of the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have each dictionary entry a list, so you append to that list.

```
>>> a = Linter("ahahah")
>>> a.write_file()
>>> a = dict()
>>> a["first"] = []
>>> a["first"].append([1,2,3])
>>> a["first"].append([4,5,6])
>>> a["second"] = []
>>> a["second"].append([7,8,9])
>>> a
{
 'second':[  
              [7, 8, 9]
          ], 
 'first': [  
              [1, 2, 3], 
              [4, 5, 6]
          ]
}
```

but honestly, at some point just consider using classes?

Comment: Huh, ok. I'll try it. And classes scare me. Never touched them before. Not against it though.

Comment: @Thisisstackoverflow; trust me, they look a bit "scary" at first because they have all those `__` methods and the names change (i.e. functions in a class are called methods, etc..) but it's worth it. If you are following a tutorial then just follow it along and don't skip ahead to classes. They will most likely come soon enough in the book/tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
>>> d={'a': ['b']}
>>> d['a']
['b']
>>> d['a'] += ['c']
>>> d['a']
['b', 'c']
```

Comment: note that the author said a value could also be multiple lists (I assume list of lists). It's completely unclear what is asked for.

Comment: That is one list. What I'm looking for are multiple lists within one key.

Comment: what do you mean by multiple lists? list of lists?

Comment: To the discussion here, this are lists of lists. @pianista; created a dictionary with a list containing string "b". Then he said ["b"] (which is a list) + ["c"] (which is also a list). In python doing [1]+[2] is [1,2], that is "adding" lists concatenates them into larger lists. This is also a valid answer because `[1]+[2, [1,2]]` is `[1, 2, [1, 2]]`

Comment: I edited my post. ljetibo's answer is what I was looking for. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to accomplish what you need.

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(list)
my_dict[1].append([1,2])
my_dict[1].append([3,4])
my_dict[2].append([8,9])
```

Now you can access each key element as you would access a `dictionary`

```
>>> my_dict[1]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]


>>> for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
        print k,v

1 [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
2 [[8, 9]]
```

Comment: This looks like it will work as well, and is a little cleaner to look at. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. The counter module is pretty useful. Make sure to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
class My_Dictionary(dict):

    def __init__(self):
        self = dict()

    def add(self, key, value):
        try:
            self[key].append(value)
        except KeyError:
            self[key] = [value]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dict_obj = My_Dictionary()
    key = 0
    take_1 = [1,6,2,4]
    take_2 = [7,3,5,6]
    dict_obj.add(key, take_1)
    dict_obj.add(key, take_2)
    print(dict_obj)
```

This code will return a dictionary in your desired format.
{0: [[1, 6, 2, 4], [7, 3, 5, 6]]}